# Cloud function to reset users password isn't working

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-functions, firebase-admin

I am working on a web app, and part of the functionality of the app is having an admin login and be able to reset a user's password. I am using firebase cloud functions.

```
resetForm.addEventListener('submit', (e) => {
        console.log("Step 1");
        e.preventDefault();
        let newPass = resetForm['reset-password'].value;
        const resetPasswordFunction = firebase.functions().httpsCallable('resetPassword');
        resetPasswordFunction(docId,newPass).then(() => {
            const modal = document.querySelector('#modal-reset');
          M.Modal.getInstance(modal).close();
          resetForm.reset();
        })
        console.log("Step 1.5");
    });
```

.

```
var functions = require('firebase-functions');
var admin = require("firebase-admin");
var serviceAccount = require("./troop-30-elections-web-app-firebase-adminsdk-obsmr-6913a9dca3.json");
admin.initializeApp({
  credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
  databaseURL: "https://troop-30-elections-web-app.firebaseio.com"
});

exports.resetPassword = functions.https.onCall((docId,newPass) => {
    console.log("step 2");
    admin.auth().updateUser(docId, {
        password: newPass,
    });
});
```

I tested it by filling out the form, and nothing happened. I looked in the console and there were no errors, but I saw Step 1 and Step 1.5.

Comment: Any specific reason why you are using a Service Account to initialize `firebase-admin`? `firebase-admin` should normally been initialized without any parameters within the Cloud Functions runtime, see https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/beta-v1-diff#new_initialization_syntax_for_firebase-admin

Comment: Oh. Thank you. I thought you needed a service account. I read this: https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup#initialize-sdk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did more research and edited my code. This works:

```
resetForm.addEventListener('submit', (e) => {
        console.log("Step 1");
        e.preventDefault();
        let newPass = resetForm['reset-password'].value;
        const resetPasswordFunction = firebase.functions().httpsCallable('resetPassword');
        resetPasswordFunction({docId: docId, newPass: newPass}).then(() => {
            const modal = document.querySelector('#modal-reset');
          M.Modal.getInstance(modal).close();
          resetForm.reset();
        });
        console.log("Step 1.5");
    });
```

.

```
var functions = require('firebase-functions');
var admin = require("firebase-admin");
var serviceAccount = require("./troop-30-elections-web-app-firebase-adminsdk-obsmr-6913a9dca3.json");
admin.initializeApp({
  credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
  databaseURL: "https://troop-30-elections-web-app.firebaseio.com"
});

exports.resetPassword = functions.https.onCall((data) => {
  return admin.auth().updateUser(data.docId, { 
    password: data.newPass
   })
  .then(() => {
      return {"text": "User Password Successfully Updated"};  // this is what gets sent back to the app
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

For callable type functions, you are obliged to return a promise that yields the value of the object to send back to the client app that invoked it.  That promise must only resolve when all of the asynchronous work is complete, else the function will shut down before the work is complete.

Right now, your function is returning nothing, and ignoring the promise returned by [updateUser()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/admin.auth.Auth-1#updateuser).  Cloud Functions is terminating the function before the work is complete: the promise is being ignored.  Your code should instead use that promise and send a result back to the client.  This will send an empty object, but you can do whatever you want in it:

```
    return admin.auth().updateUser(docId, { password: newPass })
    .then(() => {
        return {};  // this is what gets sent back to the app
    });
```

Comment: Thank you. Can I just leave it empty, or do I need to put something in it? If so then what?

Comment: What do you want the client app to receive?  Put that there.  It can be anything represented as JSON.

Comment: I don't think it needs to receive anything. It just needs to update the users password.

Comment: Then send whatever you want.  You can't avoid sending something.  There will always be a response.

Comment: I added the following: {"text": "User Password Successfully Updated"}
I tested it by filling out the form and I got the following error: 
Uncaught (in promise) Error: INTERNAL

Comment: You might have another new problem which needs debugging.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/225903/discussion-between-wbhill13-and-doug-stevenson).

Comment: I figured out that the problem was caused because I needed to pass in an object instead of two strings. I passed in data and wrote this:  resetPasswordFunction({docId: docId, newPass: newPass})...